# How can I cheaply restore my waxed jacket?

Tags: clothing, water

My father-in-law gave me a [Filson waxed jacket](https://www.filson.com/outerwear/foul-weather-jacket.html) and one tin of wax that I ran out of (or misplaced) and the tin never really covered the whole jacket and now its out of stock on filson's website and 5x the normal price on amazon.

Is there a way to use materials I can find at the grocery or hardware store to make something similar to what is used in a filson oil coat wax to waterproof my coat and make it last longer?

Comment: There are *many* leather oils and waxes, such as neatsfoot oil (from cattle feet), carnauba wax (from palm leaves), etc. Look online for "leather wax or oil" for a less expensive type.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik does it matter that it is not a leather jacket - it's oilcloth or something like that - kinda like a stiff duckcloth?

Comment: If it were mine, I'd try a carnauba-based (hard) wax. *Caveat!* Waxed canvas is flammable, and a real hazard around a campfire or trail kitchen.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - you really don't want a hard wax on a flexible item of clothing - it's somewhat counter-productive. It will crack & leak. It must stay flexible.

Comment: @Tetsujin, pure carnauba wax is hard and brittle, as you state -- but the leather waxes have additives to make it more flexible. In any event, due to flammability, I'd avoid waxed fabric garments.

Comment: I still wouldn't get any wax that didn't specifically state it was for waxed jackets. tbh, I wouldn't get anything other than Barbour myself. And though you'd of course think waxed fabric could be a fire risk, there is not one single reference I can find to that online.

Answer (score 2):

I know this site is for 'hacks' but I wouldn't hack an expensive wax jacket.

Do an Amazon [or similar] search for "wax for wax jacket".
Everybody who makes wax jackets, from Barbour to Fjällräven, and even some who don't make clothing but only make clean/protect products have one.

I'd get one I've at least *heard* of, Barbour, Grangers in the UK - likely different by territory - even if they're more expensive. [BTW, don't cross-type, ie don't put beeswax on a regular wax jacket - they don't combine well.]

…And don't just buy some random wax type. You wouldn't put shoe polish on your car, or car wax on your shoes. Don't do it with wax jackets either. The wax needs to be readily absorbed & stay flexible when dry, otherwise it will crack off & leak.